# how to plot states of a state space having time delayed states in matlab?

Tags: nonlinear-functions, timedelay, state-space

I am working on a research article

> Local Stabilization of Time-Delay Nonlinear Discrete-Time Systems
>   Using Takagi-Sugeno Models and Convex Optimization

written by  Luís F. P. Silva, Valter J. S. Leite, Eugênio B. Castelan, and Michael Klug.

In this paper we get a state space like

```
dx = A*x + Ad * xd
```

here `x` are the states of system and `xd` are the delayed states.

I am getting confused that how do we plot the states of this system.

Answer (score 1):

Possibilities:

- The simplest thing to do is to plot the states of the system `x` against time as separate variables.
- If the dimensionality is low (say <3), like in the example 4.1 at page 7, you can plot the phase space against time, as done in Figure 1, as a [parametric curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametric_equation). See also [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_space#Phase_plot) entry of Wikipedia.
- If the dimensionality is high, you may use [Taken](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Takens'_theorem)'s embedding theorem to reduce the dimensionality. See in particular the "Simplified, slightly inaccurate version" for how to do it.

Comment: Thank you  for your help.

actually i know about phase portraits...

the thing creating trouble is that...

if  i have a differential equations like this...

dx1 =  2*x    +  3*xd ;
dx2 =  0.5*x  +  2*xd ;

Comment: what about it? Clearly if you are dealing with delayed differential equations the problem has infinite dimensionality. This does not mean that you can't plot the state variable `x` at a certain time. And of course the evolution of the system will also depend on history.

Comment: should i use dde23 command for this instead of ode45 in matlab..?

Comment: if the problem is a delayed differential equation, yes.